# MS SQL Get Table Row With Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two seperate database with the same table structure but with different data. My database "a" got a table named articles with the columns of id, heading, detail and date. Database "b" also got the identical table.

For example:

a database has 10 rows.

b database has 12 rows.

Is there anyway to get the 3 selected row from a and transfer it to the b with the data that rows hold.

Comment: What three selected rows?

Comment: There are three rows among the ten rows present in a which are not present in the set of twelve rows in b? It seems you are looking for a **database link**, so you can actually access both tables in one query and thus determine the missing rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reasonable interpretation of the question is that you want to move rows from `a.dbo.articles` to `b.dbo.articles` that are not already there:

```
insert into b.dbo.articles(id, heading, detail, date)
    select id, heading, detail, date
    from a.dbo.articles a
    where not exists (select 1 from  b.dbo.articles b where b.id = a.id);
```

Notes:

- This assumes that the two databases are on the same server.  Otherwise, you need a database link.
- This assumes that the `id` is sufficient for the comparison.  If not, just add the right logic to the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Insert Into DatabaseB.MyTable (id, heading, detail date)
Select id, heading, detail date
From DatabaseA.MyTable Limit 3`